# Do some client side validation before posting to server - browser issue

Tags: javascript, html, forms, client-server

I have a form where I'm posting to `PHP` server page. Before I `POST` I do some validation test on the client side, if all good I return `true` and then submit starts, if there's problems I return `false` and the submit cancel.

```
<form  onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post" action="t5.php">
```

and the validation function :

```
function validateForm() {

    email = document.getElementById('email').value;
    name = document.getElementById('name').value;

    if ((name==="")|| (email=="") ) {
       document.getElementById('validateError').innerHTML="error text";


       return false;
    }
    else
  return true;

};
```

This logic works on last Chrome version, but tried this on Chrome 19 and Firefox and its returns `false` but still doing immediately a submit.
any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead on calling your validate function on "onsubmit", you can call a similar function on a button click and then if no errors, submit the form via code

Try something like

```
<form name="testform" id="testform" method="post" action="t5.php">

    <input type="text" name="name" id="name"/>
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email"/>
    <input type="button" name="Submit" value="Submit" onclick="validateSubmitForm();"/>
</form>
```

validateSubmitForm function might have something like this

```
function validateSubmitForm() {
   var email = document.getElementById('email').value;
   var name = document.getElementById('name').value;

   if ((name=="")|| (email=="") ) {
     document.getElementById('validateError').innerHTML="error text";
   }
   else {
     document.testform.submit();
   }
}
```

Comment: Tried it...it get into the function, show the error message,and after getting out of the function,do the post of the form.

Comment: Did it do what you were trying to do then? Or did you want something else?

Comment: I tried it on Firefox 21 version, and it's not working as needed. it still getting out from the function and doing POST after that.

Comment: Can you put some console.logs within each branch(in if and then again in else) and put your complete updated code? I don't think the version would matter with a simple branching logic. I cannot see how it can both display the 'error text' and then 'submit the form' with a similar code. It might get into the function and then 'submit the form' without getting into the 'error text' condition but not do both

Comment: Damn what a mistake...It didn't worked because my button was `input type="submit" `, after I changed it to `type="button"` all worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `preventDefault()` to stop the form from submtting.

and `HTMLFormElement.submit()` to submit if everything is Ok.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one :

**Java script**

```
function validateForm(e) {

    email = document.getElementById('email').value;
    name = document.getElementById('name').value;

    if ((name=="")|| (email=="") ) {
       document.getElementById('validateError').innerHTML="error text";
       e.preventDefault();
    }


};
```

**HTML**

```
<form  onsubmit="validateForm(event)" method="post" action="t5.php">
```

Comment: Tried it, it works the same... after  `e.preventDefault();` it still returns to the form (debugged it) and then do a POST.

Comment: Make sure you have no syntax error there within the function. It is working for me. Are you sure that you have elements with ids "email", "name" and "validateError"

Comment: I don't, it works on Firefox,and in my last Chrome version, but trying it on 11 Chrome version - it's not working.